# iOS ipa is killed just after clicked on the app icon

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, osx-yosemite, ipa

I build my ipa through my CI system. It's working well, my ipa is generated, as usual.

But when I install it on a device, and then tap on the app icon, the app launches and it's killed directly. I have this behaviour when the app is built on my macmini (OSX 10.10, Xcode 6.1).

When I build the app on my mac (OSX 10.10, Xcode 6.1), with the same command lines, the app is working well on my iPhone.

Any idea, why it's not working on the macmini ? It used to work well, but since 2 months it's doing this weird thing.

On both macs, I've got the right Certificates and mobileprovision. I checked the ipa generated, both have the embedded.mobileprovision with the right UDID.

Here is my code to build ipa :

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme "MyScheme" -destination=build -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos7.0 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES clean build archive


# Common path and partial filename
ARCHIVE_BASEPATH="${HOME}/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/${XCODE_SCHEME}"

# Find the latest .xcarchive for the given scheme
NEW_ARCHIVE=$(ls -td "${ARCHIVE_BASEPATH}"* | head -n 1)

# Export 
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat "IPA" -archivePath "$NEW_ARCHIVE" -exportPath ./MyAPP.ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "My Distribution provisionning profile"
```

[Update] Here is the log of the crash :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAssetsLibrary.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/03823DE6-B2FD-4A2D-B03F-3770D433CBCA/Lima.app/Lima
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/03823DE6-B2FD-4A2D-B03F-3770D433CBCA/Lima.app/Frameworks/libswiftAssetsLibrary.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x00871000, size=0x00004000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/03823DE6-B2FD-4A2D-B03F-3770D433CBCA/Lima.app/Frameworks/libswiftAssetsLibrary.dylib
  Dyld Version: 353.5
```

Thanks !

Comment: Check the iOS devices log, you app might crash or there might be something wrong with the profile.

Comment: Yeah go to the console on the organizer on a crashing iPhone, it look likes a provisioning problem ;)

Comment: Yep thanks guys, just update my post. I'm gonna look about libSwiftAssetsLybrary

Comment: Im having same issue only in Prod version  when built in Jenkins . Any clue on the solution .